# Liquid Template is not showing object properties

Tags: node.js, mongoose, liquid

I am making a template of liquid in which i get the data from mongodb collection and then want to use in liquid. MongoDB return array of objects and when i pass that array to liquid then it does not show in template and make the empty template.

I tried to give different objects but it's not showing object property. But when i pass static data then it easily show in template without any error.

```
export const AdamBalanceTemplate = ({ data, save = true, folder, template }) => {
  const create = async (fileName) => {
    const _path = path.join(__dirname, folder);

    const engine = new Liquid({
      root: _path, // Specify the root directory of templates
      extname: '.liquid', // Specify the extension of your templates
    });

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        let sampleArray = [];
        await data?.transactions.forEach(element => {
          sampleArray.push(element)
        });

        console.log(sampleArray)
        // Update the data with dynamic heading and bold dates
        const updatedData = {
          heading: data.heading || 'Statement of Money Transfers Between Adam and Torben',
          fromDate: `${data.fromDate}`,
          toDate: `${data.toDate}`,
          transactions: sampleArray|| [],
        };


        const html = await engine.renderFile(template, updatedData);

        if (save) {
          // when save is true, generate a PDF and save it to the "upload" folder
          fileName = (fileName === undefined || fileName.length === 0) ? `${Date.now()}.pdf` : `${fileName}.pdf`;
          const _pdfPath = path.join(__dirname, `../uploads/${fileName}`);

          const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.setContent(html);
          await page.pdf({ path: _pdfPath, format: 'A4' });
          await browser.close();

          return resolve(_pdfPath);
        }

        // otherwise just return the PDF buffer
        // const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        // const page = await browser.newPage();
        // await page.setContent(html);
        // const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
        // await browser.close();
        // resolve(pdfBuffer);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(new FailServerError('Unable to create PDF template of the document'));
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    create,
  };
};
```